# Read all fields in a form

Tags: php, forms, email

This "formmail.asp" ASP script receive an:

```
<form action="formmail.asp" method="POST">
```

Read ALL Fields in form, build a msg with all fields and send to my email this fields and yours values.

```
msg = empty

for each field in Request.Form() // read ALL fields in form
    select case lcase(field) // small cap field_name
    case "subject","cco","cc","to","lines","redirect","importance","split","submit","b1","hidden" // ignore some fields
    case else
        msg = msg & (field & " = " & Request.Form(field) & chr(13) & chr(10)) // append a line: field_name = field_value
    end select
next
```

Please, how can I convert this part from ASP to PHP?

Comment: [SO is not a code translation service](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129362/164367)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$msg='';
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$val) 
  if (!in_array($key, array("subject","cco","cc","to","lines","redirect","importance","split","submit","b1","hidden"))
    $msg .= "$key = $val\n";
```